# print text in bold in webpage

Tags: html, perl

I have a perl script which generates the output and display in webpage (in Nagios).

So from the output I want to display particular line (called heading) in BOLD in script output as well as in webpage

I am trying to use below- It display bold (Heading1) in command line But not in Nagios webpage.

```
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);
$Term::ANSIColor::AUTORESET = 1;

sub display
{
    print BOLD ("Heading1:\n");
}
```

Could see in Webpage it displays followed with number But NO BOLD.

```
[1mHeading1:
```

Comment: If you want to show something bold in HTML use the `<b>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Term::ANSIColor allows you to change the aspect of the text printed to the terminal (via the command line interface, CLI).
Web pages are simple text documents that are *rendered* by the browser, as long as you use valid HTML/CSS/JavaScript code.

To print *bold* text in HTML you should print something like:

```
print "<b>This text is bold</b> <br>\n";
```

where the *b* tag is for bold, and *br* is the line break (*i.e.* equivalent to the `\n` in command line context). This snippet is to clarify how HTML tags work (see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp for more).

I agree with TFBW and you can use HTML-rendere downstream, or if you want more control and at the same time produce good HTML code you can use some Perl module for this (https://metacpan.org/search?size=20&q=html).

As a final comment, I personally use Term::ANSIColor only for scripts that I personally run, as seeing the scrolling text can be confusing an some colors will drive through the different informations. scripts that generate (usually dynamic) web pages are typically writing their text to a log file, making the colors less useful and possibly difficult to read.

Answer (score 3):

The means by which web pages and terminals create effects such as colours and styles is very different. The web uses HTML, a markup language with tags and style sheets. Terminals use control codes and escape sequences. There is no single output you can generate which will work for both.

You could, however, generate HTML output and pipe your output through an HTML-renderer for the console when operating on the console. Alternatively, you could create a set of functions for the styles you want (like bold), and have them produce different output depending on whether the destination is a terminal or not. You can test whether STDOUT is a terminal using `-t STDOUT`.